# Redirection using routing module

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have a login page and after login in I am redirecting to a dashboard. The dashboard has some children pages also. I need that when you be logged in and click in the logo I be redirected to the dashboard and if I am not logged in I be redirected to the login page. Here is an example of my code:

**navbar.component.html**

```
<mat-toolbar>
    <h1>
      <a routerLink="/">
        <img src="../image.jpg"/>
      </a>
    </h1>
  </mat-toolbar>
```

**routing.module.ts**

```
.
.
.
const routes: Routes = [
  {
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
      {
        path: 'login',
        component: ClientLayoutComponent,
        children: [
          { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
          {
            path: 'dashboard',
            component: DashboardComponent,
            canActivate: [DashboardGuard],
          },
          {
            path: 'account',
            component: AccountComponent
          },
          { path: 'Blog', component: BlogComponent },
        ],
      },
  },
];
```

The steps are so clear:

1. If I am not logged in, when I click in the logo it have to go to login page or,
2. If I am logged in, when I click in the logo it have to go to dashboard page

Answer (score 1):

I would separate the login path and the dashboard path. If you want to deny access to the dashboard (if not logged in) I would suggest to use a route guard.

A fast (dirty) way to do it is to create two logo links and serve the correct one based on if the user is logged in or not:

e.g:

```js
# in the component, create an variable that holds the value if a user is logged or not

<a *ngIf="userIsLoggedIn === false" routerLink="/login">
    <img src="../image.jpg"/>
</a>

<a *ngIf="userIsLoggedIn() === true" routerLink="/dashboard">
    <img src="../image.jpg"/>
</a>
```

Other options: Do a `(click)="yourFunction()"` on the anchor of your logo. In `yourFunction()` you check if the user is logged in or not and them navigate them to the correct page.

Comment: And what about if I need a function in routing.module.ts to check some conditions and follow to correct route? I am not sure how do that

Comment: Could you give an example? What function would you need in your routing module?

Comment: I am not sure. I just know that I have to do it using functions but I don't know what it means.